# How to get villagename, district and subdistrict from latitude longitude

Tags: android, google-maps, geolocation, location

I have the latitude and longitude co-ordinate and I want to get the village name district and sub district from that. I searched and found reverse geocode which does not give the village name.
Is there any api or codebase for getting exact location from lat long. I want to show that in my android app.

```
Geocoder geocoder = new Geocoder(this, Locale.getDefault());
        String result = null;
        try {
            List<Address> addressList = geocoder.getFromLocation(
                    25.882456,83.174279, 1);
            if (addressList != null && addressList.size() > 0) {
                Address address = addressList.get(0);
                StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
                for (int i = 0; i < address.getMaxAddressLineIndex(); i++) {
                    sb.append(address.getAddressLine(i)).append("\n");//adress
                }
                sb.append(address.getLocality()).append("\n");//village

                sb.append(address.getPostalCode()).append("\n");
                sb.append(address.getCountryName());
                sb.append(address.getAdminArea()).append("\n"); //state

                sb.append(address.getSubAdminArea()).append("\n");//district


                result = sb.toString();
            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
           // Log.e(TAG, "Unable connect to Geocoder", e);
        }
```

Comment: Please show your code, and mention in which case it doesn't work.

Comment: Can you show us what is the "result" ? I've never used, but, looking in the API, I saw that it returns the info in JSON, you take care about it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i changed in ur code and it is working

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Locale;

import android.app.AlertDialog;
import android.content.Context;
import android.location.Address;
import android.location.Geocoder;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity;
import android.util.Log;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.google.android.gms.maps.GoogleMap;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.BitmapDescriptorFactory;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.LatLng;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.Marker;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.MarkerOptions;

public class MainActivity extends FragmentActivity {
    private GoogleMap mMap;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
        setUpMapIfNeeded();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        setUpMapIfNeeded();
    }

    private void setUpMapIfNeeded() {
        if (mMap != null) {
            return;
        }
        mMap = ((SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map)).getMap();
        if (mMap == null) {
            return;
        }
        // Initialize map options. For example:
        // mMap.setMapType(GoogleMap.MAP_TYPE_HYBRID);

        final LatLng INDIA = new LatLng(28.5192, 77.2130);

      //  String address=getAddress(this, 28.5192, 77.2130);
        Marker melbourne = mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
                                  .position(INDIA)
                                  .title("Saket")
                                  .snippet("Population: 4,137,400"));
       // String address=getAddress(this,28.6700, 77.4200);

        Geocoder geocoder = new Geocoder(this, Locale.getDefault());
        String result = null;
        try {
            List<Address> addressList = geocoder.getFromLocation(
                    25.882456,83.174279, 1);
            if (addressList != null && addressList.size() > 0) {
                Address address = addressList.get(0);
                StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
                for (int i = 0; i < address.getMaxAddressLineIndex(); i++) {
                    sb.append(address.getAddressLine(i)).append("\n");//adress
                }
                sb.append(address.getLocality()).append("\n");//village

                sb.append(address.getPostalCode()).append("\n");
                sb.append(address.getCountryName());
                sb.append(address.getAdminArea()).append("\n"); //state

                sb.append(address.getSubAdminArea()).append("\n");//district

               sb.append(address.getSubLocality()).append("\n");

                result = sb.toString();
            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
           // Log.e(TAG, "Unable connect to Geocoder", e);
        }
        new AlertDialog.Builder(this).setMessage(result).create().show();

        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), result, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        final LatLng Ghaziabad = new LatLng(24.1860076, 75.1432231);
        Marker ghaziabad = mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
                                  .position(Ghaziabad)
                                  .title(result)
                                  .snippet("Population: 4,137,400")
                                  .icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromResource(R.drawable.ic_launcher)));


    }
```